# error when use magisk to root android studio emulator P API 28

Tags: python, powershell, administrator

I got error when try to use build.py all in effort installing magisk to android emulator pie api 28

```
PS C:\temp\repos\Magisk> python build.py all

* Building binaries: magisk magiskinit magiskboot magiskpolicy busybox

error: failed to run custom build command for `cxx-gen v0.7.94 (C:\temp\repos\Magisk\native\src\external\cxx-rs\gen\lib)`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\temp\repos\Magisk\native\src\target\debug\build\cxx-gen-69026a18f023ca9c\build-script-build` (exit code: 1)
  --- stderr

  When building `cxx` from a git clone, git's symlink support needs
  to be enabled on platforms that have it off by default (Windows).
  Either use:

     $ git config --global core.symlinks true

  prior to cloning, or else use:

     $ git clone -c core.symlinks=true https://github.com/dtolnay/cxx

  for the clone.

  Symlinks are only required when compiling locally from a clone of
  the git repository---they are NOT required when building `cxx` as
  a Cargo-managed (possibly transitive) build dependency downloaded
  through crates.io.
```

how to fix that?
ive enabled symlink and developer mode

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version 10.0.19045 Build 19045
python 3.8
jdk 8
android studio flamingo
git
```

Comment: Just to point out one potential problem: The error message implies that if you use the `git config` command, you must run it _before_ cloning the repo.

Comment: What part of this question involves `powershell`?

Answer (score 0):

If you would just need a root shell, you can do `adb root` as long as the system image is compiled with `userdebug` by default.

If you would like to install Magisk anyways, there's a script for your convenience: https://github.com/newbit1/rootAVD

Comment: it doesnt work too, ive tried using rootavd , setting path android_home etc,
rootavd.bat  installapps
rootavd.bat